# Why does MD13S JST have an NC pin?

Tags: pcb-design, connector, motor-controller

This is about the 4-pin JST connector that links the driver to a microcontroller. It seems that the only important pins are GND, PWM (speed), and DIR (direction). Clearly, when Cytron has designed the driver from the ground up, why would they add an NC (which I assume is "no connect") to the driver (instead of using a 3-pin JST)? Isn't it a waste?

I am using one of these motor drivers for a college project. The people worked on it before me had kindly soldered a 3-pin JST header to it, so I never gave this much thought before.

Motor driver product page, for reference: https://www.cytron.io/c-motor-driver/p-13amp-6v-30v-dc-motor-driver

Comment: Why are you asking us and not cytron? All we can do is guess. My guess would be that it's to use the same connector as some other version of the module that does use that pin for some feature this version doesn't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They claim it is "Grove compatible", which refers to a [hobbyist ecosystem](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove_System/) using connectors with pins 3 and 4 devoted to Vcc and GND respectively. The English is a bit painful but:

```
**Interface of Grove modules**
You may notice that there're 4 color of the Grove cable.

pin 1 - Yellow (for example, SCL on I2C Grove Connectors)
pin 2 - White (for example, SDA on I2C Grove Connectors)
pin 3 - Red - VCC on all Grove Connectors
pin 4 - Black - GND on all Grove Connectors
```

That allows the use of common mass-produced cables and standard breakout boards to connect to something like an Arduino Uno. I don't see a schematic, but this particular module probably draws its power from the motor power supply.